# Facebook plugin shows existing comments

Tags: plugins, comments, facebook

Installed the official facebook [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook/) and seems to be working.
The problem is that existing comments are still visible (with default style) above facebook comments form.

My `comments.php` is empty now and I see this. (Sorry about greek text, no time to change it). I emptied it because I know there is no merge possible, so moving to the fb-comments only era on this site.

Is there a way to completely remove the existing comments, or at least style them and move them after fb ones? I see no option in the backoffice of the plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use this plugin, but it looks like [this comment template](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/facebook/tags/1.4/social-plugins/comments.php)  is [loaded](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/facebook/tags/1.4/facebook.php#L362) with

```
add_filter( 'comments_template', array( 'Facebook_Comments', 'comments_template' ) );
```

The simplified structure of this comment template looks like:

```
if ( have_comments() ) :
    // ...
    wp_list_comments( $_comment_options );
    // ...
endif; 

$_facebook_comments = Facebook_Comments::comments_box();
if ( $_facebook_comments ) {
       do_action( 'facebook_comment_form_before' );
       echo '<div id="respond">';
       echo $_facebook_comments;
       echo '</div>';
       do_action( 'facebook_comment_form_after' );
}
```

Then you could try to let `have_comments()` return `false` to skip the WordPress comments part.

Checking the core, we [find](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/query.php#L801) that:

```
function have_comments() {
    global $wp_query;
    return $wp_query->have_comments();
 }
```

where the class method is defined as

```
function have_comments() {
    if ( $this->current_comment + 1 < $this->comment_count ) {
        return true;
    } elseif ( $this->current_comment + 1 == $this->comment_count ) {
         $this->rewind_comments();
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can then try

```
function skip_wp_comments() {   
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->current_comment = 999; // large number
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'skip_wp_comments' );
```

to let `have_comments()` return `false`.

If that doesn't work you could overwrite the `comments_template` filter to use your own template or try to play with the `comment_count` part.

Comment: I only can upvote once.. sorry about that! Excelent answer. Thank you

Comment: thanks, I´m surprised that this isn't an option in the plugin ;-)